# Why does SSL work on a Puma development app but not when it's running in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, puma

I have a Puma app running in development mode that I'm able to configure behind an Nginx server with SSL, but when I try to do the same with that Puma app running in production mode I am having troubles.

Relevant code:

nginx.conf:

```
upstream puma_lbm_app {
  server lbm:40000;
}

server {
  listen 40000 ssl default_server;

  server_name         www.*.com;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/LBM/certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/LBM/private/server.key;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  error_page 500 502 504 /500.html;
  error_page 503 @503;

  server_name localhost puma_lbm_app;
  root /usr/src/app/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_lbm_app;

  location @puma_lbm_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
    fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;

    proxy_pass https://puma_lbm_app;
    # limit_req zone=one;
    access_log /usr/src/app/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /usr/src/app/log/nginx.error.log;
  }
}
```

puma.rb:

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum, this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests, default is 3000.
#
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 40000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" } # this is development when running our dev Puma app
bind 'tcp://0.0.0.0'

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).
#
# workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory. If you use this option
# you need to make sure to reconnect any threads in the `on_worker_boot`
# block.
#
# preload_app!

# The code in the `on_worker_boot` will be called if you are using
# clustered mode by specifying a number of `workers`. After each worker
# process is booted this block will be run, if you are using `preload_app!`
# option you will want to use this block to reconnect to any threads
# or connections that may have been created at application boot, Ruby
# cannot share connections between processes.
#
# on_worker_boot do
#   ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
# end

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

dockerfile for production:

```
FROM ruby:2.3-alpine

RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies build-base ruby-dev \
    openssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev sqlite libc-dev linux-headers nodejs \
    tzdata sqlite-dev bind-tools curl postgresql-client \
    postgresql-dev

RUN gem install bundler

ENV RAILS_ENV production

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
ADD http://browserconfig.*.com/*-certs/*-ca-bundle.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
RUN bundle install

EXPOSE 40000

CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

dockerfile for development:

```
FROM ruby:2.3-alpine

RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies build-base ruby-dev \
    openssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev sqlite libc-dev linux-headers nodejs \
    tzdata sqlite-dev bind-tools curl postgresql-client \
    postgresql-dev

RUN gem install bundler

ENV RAILS_ENV development

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
ADD http://browserconfig.*.com/*-certs/*-ca-bundle.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
RUN bundle install
RUN rake db:migrate

EXPOSE 40000

CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Through minor tweaks to the nginx.conf and the puma.conf I'm able to get 307s, 502s...but it never shows up fine like the app does when running in development.

Comment: have you tried uncommenting the `config.force_ssl = true` line in `production.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

So it was working the whole time. The issues came from production not hosting the 'Yay! You're on Rails' page that development shows. We were also testing with Postman and are seeing some separate issues with how we're handling headers.